# How do I make a case insensitive compare between two Unicode characters or strings under Windows in C/C++?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

I'm looking for a way of doing a insensitive compare of two Unicode characters (char32) under Windows (C/C++, not .NET).

I am aware that the solution is supposed to be locale aware.

I would like a solution that would not require additional third-party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is that you should lookup [`CompareStringEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647477(VS.85).aspx) with its parameters `LOCALE_INVARIANT` and `NORM_IGNORECASE`.

Answer (score 0):

**Whoops, you want to compare char32s.  Ignore my post.**

**My original answer**

> For posterity:
>
> You can use
>
> ```
> _wcsicmp(const wchar_t *string1, const wchar_t *string2) or
>
> _mbsicmp(const unsigned char_t *string1, const unsigned char *string2)
> ```
>
> the former compares wide characters
>   (usually UTF-16) and the latter
>   compares multi-byte characters
>   (usually UTF-8).  You need to set the
>   code page using
>
> ```
> _setmbcp(int codepage)
> ```

Comment: char32 is 32bit (UTF-32), wchar_t is 16 bits (UTF16-LE).

Comment: wchar_t is UCS-2 for all practical purposes. The widestring functions don't treat widestring as variable character length; that's the whole point of having them.